# Is it possible to launch waze from Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using angular.js and Ionic,
Is it possible to launch waze app with ionic ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch any external app with this plugin: https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp
You just need to know package name, it can be a problem if that app doesn't exist, so you may want to check if specific package exist before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Official page have a plugin that can do that. Please refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61222712/3967044)