# Open Apps for Android in Ionic

Tags: android, dictionary, ionic-framework

I'm currently developing a mobile app for iOS and Android using Ionic Framework, I have my own Map API but lacking navigation function...

When user click on the POI then my app can open other Map App for example Google Map or Waze to straight away navigate to that place.

For iOS, my app can straight away open Waze without any problem, but for Android either it can't be open or it just open the link in browser.

So what is the way for opening Waze in android using URI? Or it must be using some plugin?

```
if(ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
    window.open('waze://?ll=' + location + '&navigate=yes');
} else if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {   
    window.open('geo:' + location + '?&q=' + location);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try `http://waze.to`. This forum link may be of use: https://www.waze.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17684

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is 4 years old. Just in case anyone come across to this question, and hoping for an answer. Please refer to official documentation at [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/launch-navigator) and [github](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator)