# Show waze map in my ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, waze

I want to create an app that show the route between the current location and the user input location, so I want to show two option, the first the google maps route and the another waze maps, the google maps it's ok, I got. But the waze I didn't get find any thing about it. So my ask is, Have one plugin or something that make the waze maps show inside of my ionic?

Answer (score 1):

Launch Navigator is helping you to open map using multiple maps app.check out this https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator-example.

Answer (score 0):

Now ionic 2 onwards support plugin to open other navigator app from ionic app. Please refer to answer at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61222712/3967044).